# Delphi 2009 using MSBuild in RAD Studio Command Prompt F1026 File not found

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-2009

I have been struggling to get the MSBuild to successfully build my .dproj file for the last few days on a build machine.

First, I needed the EnvOptions.proj file from the developer's machine, which got me clear of the missing system.pas file, but now I am getting a compile error for a missing .dcu

> C:\Program Files\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets(123,3): 
>   error : myproject.dpr(17) Fatal: F1026 File not found: 'mymissing.dcu'

Now the path to "mymissing.dcu" is included in the **Win32BrowsingPath** of the EnvOptions.proj file, and I tried adding the path to the command prompt **PATH** which also does not work.

If I copy the .dcu directly into the working directory it can be found - but this is not much of a long term solution, as there are many other .dcu files that I would need to copy into the working directory.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you installed Delphi only partially on the build machine? I have also been wondering which configuration files are necessary for MSBuild to resolve all dependencies in a Delphi dproj file.

Comment: I have fully installed Delphi, but not registered - though this is unlikely the issue as the licensed developer also has the same error message when compiling through RAD Studio Command Prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `<DCC_UnitSearchPath>` in your .dproj file.

Comment: This worked!  I copied the <Win32BrowsingPath> from EnvOptions.proj into the .dproj file as <DCC_UnitSearchPath>.

Then I followed this: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=9619 to remove (BDS)\source\Win32\rtl\sys from the unit search path.  Using the same logic I also had to remove $(BDS)\source\Win32\rtl\common.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all the environment variables referenced in library search paths, e.g. $(BDS), are actually present in the environment of the command prompt.

Comment: By using the RAD Studio Command Prompt the $(BDS) gets populated from the rsvars.bat - not the problem in this case.