# Delphi XE - Fatal: F1027 Unit not found: 'System.pas' or binary equivalents (.dcu)

Tags: delphi, msbuild, tfsbuild

During compilation of Delphi project, following error is given by the compiler:

Fatal: F1027 Unit not found: 'System.pas' or binary equivalents (.dcu)

This happens only when building though msbuild using TFS build system.

Works fine when executed through command line as below.

Command:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\msbuild.exe E:\Src\Project\sample.groupproj /v:m /t:Build /p:Config=Release

The following execution through MSbuild fails:

`<Exec Command="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\msbuild.exe E:\Src\Project\Sample.groupproj /v:m /t:Build /p:Config=Release"/>`

Note:Following env variables are set : BDS,BDSLIB,BDSCOMMONDIR,BDSINCLUDE

When executed through CCNET dcc32.exe has extra arguments such as -I,-LE,-LN,- O,-R,-U,-NB,-NH,but execution through TFS does not have the these argument list.

Any thoughts on how to resolve these errors.

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: Assuming you've run RSVars.Bat you'll also need to make sure your DCC32 config has the correct paths defined. MSBuild merely launches DCC32. Try doing a command line build using DCC32. Once you've got that working you can try and use MSBuild.

Comment: @Andy_D Yes RSVars.bat is run prior to running the msbuild  exec task . Works fine when you launch the cmd prompt and execute the the command. The error is shown when the command is encapsulated in msbuild exec task and run through TFS build system.

Comment: So you run a command prompt, call RSVars.Bat then run DCC32 <YourProjectName> and it compiles correctly? You might need to explicitly set your library paths at the project level (i.e. in your DProj file) .

Comment: @Andy_D When i run DCC32 i get a new Error, E2032 Illegal character in input file: ' " '

Comment: @Andy_D asker is using msbuild, which in turn calls dcc32.

Comment: @user you don't want to call dcc32 do you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2095231/62576

Comment: @Andy_D  Yes i am using MSBuild and not dcc32.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm fully aware of that and stated as such in an earlier comment. But if he can't compile from the command line using DCC32, he'll never get MSBuild to do it. 

Is this on your development machine or is it a build agent machine you're having the problem? I'm beginning to suspect it's a build agent and you're missing the EnvOptions.Proj file that resides in %APPDATA%\Embarcadero\xx,x\ where xx.x is your Delphi version.

Comment: @Andy The dcc32 failed because the asker passed the XML dproj file. Getting the right args to dcc32 is quite a job. And msbuild does it. Suggesting dcc32 is misleading in the extreme.

Comment: Which TFS version are you using? Did you execute MSBuild command on your build agent machine or on your local machine?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT We use TFS 2013 build system, MSBuild Command succeeds when executed manually on the build machine, but Fails when executed through TFS build system

Comment: Try to clean the cache folder on your TFS AT machine: 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services\_tfs_data

Comment: @Cece-MSFT The cache folder is empty, any other suggestion?

Comment: You need to make sure the EnvOptions.Proj file is in the %APPDATA%\Embarcadero\xx.x\ where xx.x is your Delphi version and %APPDATA% is the local app data folder *for the MSBuild user*

Comment: @Andy_D Not able to find EnvOptions.proj file in the following path: %appdata%\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0. Also not able to find this file in the installation directory.

Comment: @Andy_D When we build the same delphi projects through CCNET dcc32 has extra arguments such as -I,-LE,-LN,- O,-R,-U,-NB,-NH. Where as these arguments are missing when we build through MSBuild in TFS. Any thoughts on how to resolve these errors.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your environment is not configured properly.  First call the RSVARS.BAT file located in the BIN directory of your Delphi installation prior to calling msbuild.

If you are calling this from another build system, my suggestion would be to create a simple batch/cmd file that will call RSVARS.BAT followed by executing MSBUILD and have your build system invoke that instead.

If you try to invoke RSVARS.BAT separately, it will modify its copy of the environment then exit, which will effectively do nothing to the parent environment.  Adding a call to RSVARS.BAT from within the MSBUILD script will also fail for the same reason.  The RSVARS.BAT must be called from the same contextual environment (or higher) as the MSBUILD task.

Comment: Have done exactly the same steps as you suggested by calling RSVARS.bat through exec task(in msbuild file) and then compile delphi project.

Comment: You might need to put the call to RSVARS OUTSIDE of the exec task.  The exec task I believe will NOT copy the environment up to the parent, so the varable sets are going to be lost.  That is why I suggested using a batch file to call RSVARS first, followed by a call to the MSBUILD script.

Comment: @skamardt I am executing rsvars.bat as part of TFS pre-build script execution, then executing the msbuild project

Comment: @Santhosh, they both need to be part of the same execution context. When you execute RSVARS separately, it changes its copy of the environment, which is discarded when it completes.  If you add it as a CALL within a batch file, the environment will be modified and then the msbuild portion can use this modified environment. If you "spawn" a task to call RSVARS from within the build script, it will not work.